# Line break are too high between paragraphs with FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm using FPDF and for some reasons I have a line break which is twice as high as it should be, whether I use Multicell or Write.

```
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, "Title");
$pdf->Ln(6);

$pdf->SetFont('Times', '', 12);
$pdf->Multicell(0, 6, "First line.\n\nSecond line.",0 , 1);
```

**Results**

Title

First line.

**<-- here I have a line break twice as high as it should be, while it should be the same height as the height between the title and the first paragraph -->**

Second line.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like you should use the `Ln()` method for that, and multiple calls to `Multicell()`, like so, replace:

```
$pdf->Multicell(0, 6, "First line.\n\nSecond line.", 0, 1);
```

with

```
$pdf->Multicell(0, 6, "First line.", 0, 1); 
$pdf->Ln(6);
$pdf->Multicell(0, 6, "Second line.", 0, 1);
```

The character `\n` is a "standard" new line but the "standard" part can be highly different depending on context, whereas `Ln()` uses a specific unit.

**Edit:** Also, I just looked up in the docs that the second parameter to `Multicell()` is actually the height so you might wanna reduce that or set the align to top-align somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the end, as I'm passing an article with paragraphs, I'm exploding the content to get each line and then used foreach to pass each line into the Multicell with a line break between each of them. This works fine for me. If anyone has a better solution, please shout.

Comment: What I came up with is probably a work around. There must be a better way to do this, so I'd be best to have the answer from an expert in the field.